# How to write VISIBILITY if-else condition in ANGULARJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, if-statement

How to Write Condition on data which is fetching from Json to Angularjs?

Example : if user **FIRM NAME** exists **Show** else if user **FULL NAME** exists **Show** else **Show** **REALNAME**

I have a working Example of fetching data

at line **number 25** `<h3 class="moduletitle">Name : {{ module.realname }}</h3>`

Please See that in [**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/rkTxDvNcjge0ONdBUQE2?p=preview)

I hope i will get the working code update along with PLUNKER

Comment: <h3 ng-if="module.firm_name"  class="moduletitle">Name : {{ module.firm_name }}</h3>    If i use like this it will show everything if exists.. i need only one should be visible. Firmname or Fullname or Realname

Comment: so split them into separate checks?

Comment: Can You explain on it?

Answer (score 0):

I can suggest you have a function that returns the entity in which you want to display. Then using `ng-show` / `ng-hide` to display/hide the things you want.

Example:

```
function pseudoDecide(){
  var displaythis = "";

  if(/*boolean exp*/){ displaythis = "firm" }
  else if(/*boolean exp*/) { displaythis = "full" }
  else(/*boolean exp*/) { displaythis = "real" }

  return displaythis;
}
```

Then `<div ng-show="{{psedoDecide() === 'firm'}}>"` etc etc, something like that.

Answer (score 0):

With AngularJS 1.1.5+, you can use the ternary operator inside an expression. In your case, I believe you want something like:

```
<h3 class="moduletitle">Name : {{ module.firmname ? module.firmname : (module.fullname ? module.fullname : module.realname)) }}</h3>
```

If you don't want a nested ternary in your template, you could also go this route:

Somewhere in your controller:

```
$scope.pickName = function (module) {
  var val;

  if (module.firm_name) {
    val = module.firm_name;
  } else if (module.full_name) {
    val = module.full_name;
  } else {
      val = module.realname;
  }

  return val;
};
```

And in your template:

```
<h3 class="moduletitle">Name : <span ng-bind="pickName(module)"></span></h3>
```

Comment: You could always use ternary expression (or any other expression) in angular's templating engine.

Comment: Actually, I looked it up, and it wasn't added in 1.3, but 1.1.5: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#115-triangle-squarification-2013-05-22

Comment: I have Attempted to add this in my code      <h3 class="moduletitle">Name : {{ module.firm_name ? module.firm_name : (module.full_name ? module.full_name : module.realname)) }}</h3>      http://plnkr.co/edit/YPjLS8SSQeX106jFVeAs?p=preview

Comment: You also have a bug in your code: `module.real_name` in the expression should be `module.realname`